# Valid SSL certificate signed by own CA

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, ssl, https

**El problemo:** I want to have my own CA and emit signed certificates which can be used internally for testing purposes of android apps and REST web services communicating over HTTPS. My server of choice is Tomcat 7.
I have followed the guidelines to setup SSL using keytool on Tomcat according to the [Installing a Certificate from a Certificate Authority section](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html)  of its documentation:

```
keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keystore keystore.jks
keytool -certreq -alias tomcat -file certreq.csr -keystore keystore.jks
```

To sign the certificate sign request I use openssl:

```
openssl ca -config openssl.cnf -out server.crt -extensions android_ext \
-extfile android_ext.cnf -md sha256 -infiles certreq.csr
```

And finally I import the CA certificate and the server certificate into the keystore:

```
keytool -import -alias root -keystore keystore.jks -trustcacerts -file cacert.crt
keytool -import -alias tomcat -keystore keystore.jks -file server.crt
```

After that I setup tomcat to use keystore.jks and fire it up. If I go into Firefox and try to navigate using https I get a 'Secure Connection Failed' error.

Running openssl s_client I get [this output](https://gist.github.com/gsmiro/b52d1b48204555870b4d#file-openssl_s_client-log).

Running keytool -printcert I get [this output](https://gist.github.com/gsmiro/b52d1b48204555870b4d#file-keytool-log).

And If I run `openssl verify -CAfile .\ca\cacert.pem .\server.crt` I get:

> .\server.crt: OK

As far as my knowledge of SSL and certificates go I cannot find why when I go through Firefox I get an error. Most interestingly, using Chrome gives me a 'Connection Reset' error.

I need some help undestanding what might be wrong? Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you using the browser on the same machine that issued and imported the client, or from a different machine?

Comment: I have tried both options with same results. I'm in a LAN though - all 192.168.0.xxx addresses.

Comment: It looks like you're on Windows. Did you try installing the certs in Windows using the Certificate Manager (by typing certmgr.msc into the Search box)?

Comment: Nopes. I'll try that, although I'm pretty sure Tomcat doesn't rely on Windows for the CA's and neither does Firefox. Also I'll need this to run on linux.

Comment: Your web browser needs to _trust_ the CA that authored the certificate; for this to happen, you need to import the certificate (through browser's security options). An another thing to remember is that the certificate has to be issued to your server's domain name (otherwise you'll keep seeing warning messages about the mismatch even if the browser trusts the CA cert).

Comment: @mick-mnemonic is correct. Chrome uses the Windows cert store and for FireFox you need to install the CA cert to whatever Mozilla uses, so that the browser will be instructed to trust it.

Comment: Just for reference, I had the CA imported in FF.

Answer (score 0):

**La soluzione**

So after two days trying to figure what could've gone wrong - I posted here as a last resort - a colleague pointed that Chrome would be phasing out sha1 signed certificates - look at [this](https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2014/09/23/phasing-out-certificates-with-sha-1-based-signature-algorithms/),[this](https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2014/09/08/phasing-out-certificates-with-1024-bit-rsa-keys/) and [this](https://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.com.br/2014/09/gradually-sunsetting-sha-1.html). And apparently openssl signs with sha1 by default. So it was just a matter of creating a new cert for the CA with a stronger signature and signing it all again. Here are the commands for future reference:

```
openssl req -new -key .\private\cakey.pem.old -out .\ca\ca.csr -sha256 -config openssl.cnf
openssl x509 -req -days 8052 -sha256 -in .\ca\ca.csr -signkey .\private\cakey.pem -out ca\cacert.pem
```